# Drag and drop works for UITableView without UITableViewDropDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

According to the Apple documentation to support drag and drop for `UITableView` I have to implement `UITableViewDragDelegate` and `UITableViewDropDelegate`. I implemented only `UITableViewDragDelegate` with fake implementation for `tableView(_:itemsForBeginning:at:)` (it return empty list). But this solution works.

Why does it work?

```
    import UIKit

    class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDragDelegate {
        var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

        // MARK: - Table view drag delegate
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
            // fake implementation with empty list
            return []
        }

        // MARK: - Table view data source
        override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return data.count
        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Cell \(data[indexPath.row])"
            return cell
        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
            let tmp = data[sourceIndexPath.row]
            data.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
            data.insert(tmp, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
        }

        // MARK: - View controller
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
            self.tableView.dragDelegate = self
        }
    }
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *doesn't* work. What you are seeing is not drag and drop.

You are seeing row rearrangment, using the "reorder control". This mechanism is very old; it existed for many years before drag and drop was created. That is the effect of your implementation of

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
```

It is a UITableViewDataSource method; it has nothing to do with drag and drop. See:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614867-tableview

If you delete that method, the old row rearrangement mechanism will cease to operate, and now you'll be using drag and drop and your implementation of

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
```

will be meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know about reorder control, but asked this question because rows don't have it during reordering. I added gif to explain it.

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong, but did you actually delete `moveRowAt` as I suggested?

Comment: It really doesn't work without this method. But it also doesn't work without assigning drag delegate for the table view and it looks strange if the old approach for reordering is used.

Comment: Sure, but I believe I've answered the question. Your question was: I'm prohibiting drag and drop with my empty array, but I can reorder rows anyway. My answer is: That's because you've put in an implementation of `moveRowAt`. And my answer is right.

Comment: When `UITableViewDragDelegate` is removed, you would stop being able to reorder the table at all. Draggable reordering functionality relies on `UITableViewDragDelegate`. It has its own purpose even though it's not a pure and clean implementation. The bonus of this approach is that even if the data is a struct (i.e. not conform to NSItemProviderWriting), it still works.